# Difficulty in implementing Grover's Algorithm with large number of qubits

Tags: ibm-q-experience, grovers-algorithm

It seems IBM offers a 15 qubit quantum computer through their quantum experience program. However, upon a quick search through the literature, the largest implementation of Grover's algorithm I have seen is with 4 qubits. What seems to be preventing people from implementing Grover's algorithm with as many qubits as possible?

Comment: Nothing, just do it

Comment: Linking similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/is-there-recent-research-on-experimental-implementations-of-grovers-algorithm-w