# Is there recent research on experimental implementations of Grover's algorithm with more than 5 qubits?

Tags: grovers-algorithm, resource-request

I could only find experimental work on Grover's algorithm upto 5 qubits [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.01783.pdf). Is there any more recent research for larger database sizes where Grover's algorithm is employed? Is there any known method that is optimal to construct $C^nZ$ that is scalable for construction of Grover's algorithm with more than 5 qubits?

Comment: Linking similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9930/difficulty-in-implementing-grovers-algorithm-with-large-number-of-qubits